# Trigger Google Sheets function to write to cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have this function in Google Sheets. Currently i have to trigger it by typing `=loadOutposts()` in a field.

I have set up a time trigger on the function, but it writes no data to my sheet. Because i have not declared a sheet and field in the function to write to. How do i let the function write the data to Sheet2 A2 without having to type `=loadOutposts()`  in that field?

Thx!

```
function loadOutposts(){
  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
  if(xml) {
    var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      outpost=[rows[i].getAttribute("stationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationName").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationTypeID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("solarSystemID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationName").getValue()
                 ]
      outposts.push(outpost);
    }
  }
  return outposts;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following script code:

```
function loadOutposts(){
  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
  if(xml) {
    var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      outpost=[rows[i].getAttribute("stationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationName").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationTypeID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("solarSystemID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationName").getValue()
                 ]
      outposts.push(outpost);
    }
  }
  //return outposts;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(2,1,outposts.length,outposts[0].length).setValues(outposts);
};
```

Comment: Thanks again ;)  Works perfect!

Comment: Do you maybe know the answer to the following:

When i run the function again it now replaces all the data on Sheet2 with the new data it retrieves. 

But can it check if in the new data there are new rows, based on the combination of stationID & stationTypeID and add the new rows to the top of sheet 2?  So it does not replace all the data only add new rows?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way google sheets works, you have to directly specify when you want a function to run.

Google scripts are held server side, and so google sheets are unable to have listen events like Excel to run functions.

You could have a button on your sheet, that calls a function that passes in the selected cell, with something like this:

```
function buttonClick()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
   // Returns the active cell
   var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
   cell.setValue(loadOutposts);
}
```

This way you would need to select the cell you wish to populate and then click the button.

See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell for more information